# Limit on AWS Transit Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I see a limit on AWS Documentation for TGW that

> Number of transit gateway attachments per VPC: 5 This limit cannot be
>   increased.

As per my understanding we attach each VPC/VPN to a transit gateway by creating an attachment and we cannot create multiple attachments using same VPC. I don't understand where this limit is applicable. Please help me to understand where this is applicable exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPC interconnectivity doesn't need to be homogenous. You could have VPC A peered with VPC B and C in a mesh and then a separate mesh for VPC A, D and E. To do this you'd want 2 transit gateways.

The limit of 5 just limits each VPC to being in 5 different transit gateway meshes.

Comment: There is one more limitation 'Number of transit gateways per Region per account: 5'. I believe the number of transit gateway limitation itself covers the transit gateway attachments per VPC also (since you cannot create an attachment without transit gateway). Do you think both limitations serves different purpose?

Comment: That other limit is a soft limit. It doesn't include the phrase `This limit cannot be increased.`